# Jenkins parameter to trigger job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any type of Jenkins plugin that allows for a checkbox parameter that when selected can trigger a downstream job?

Example:
1. I am on Jenkins and have a Freestyle job.
2. This job contains multiple checkboxes that have names associated to them.
3. Based on whether these are checked it will trigger a build to a corresponding Jenkins job.

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't the section of this site which makes recommendations about software choices, this part is specifically for asking questions which are narrow in scope, and specific in nature. You can check out the software recommendations part of the site if you'd like to ask this sort of question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Have a good day!

Comment: Please use Jenkins pipeline.  You can read variable values in the script and trigger downstream projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Replace the job that you created to MultiJob (install the multijob plugin) - its the same as freestyle with additional abilities.
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuWzm.png)
3. Add Boolean parameter (let assume that the name is Mypara).
4. In the build section add Conditional step (multiple)
   Boolean condition 
   Token ${ENV,var="Mypara"}
5. Add step to condition: Trigger call builds on other project.
   (You can define if you want to wait that the downstream will block the current job run in parallel).

Good luck